# Move head node to end of list

Tags: java

I am really struggling trying to create a code that takes the head of a singly linked list and moves it to the end of the list. I'm just beginning to get frustrated because I'm so confused so I came here. If anyone could help me out and explain where to even begin with this I would greatly appreciate it. This is what I had, even though it's an infinite loop and not the right thing I thought maybe it could be a start. Thanks for any input.

```
public void flip(Node head, Node tail){
    Node temp = head;
    head = temp.next;
    head.next = null;
    tail.next = head
}
```

Comment: Play computer with pencil and paper. You have to find the last nude and change its next reference to the old head. What would that entail? If you already have the tail, it seems straight-forward, but you need some way to update the head to be the previously-second node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have `head` and `tail` as the input, you could process as :

1. Move 'head' to point to its current next

   ```
   head = head.next;
   ```
2. Make sure the current head's next is initialized to null. (since it would be the last element now)

   ```
   temp.next = null; // where temp is a new Node with head's data
   ```
3. Point 'tail.next' to this head's node

   ```
   tail.next = temp
   ```

Something like this :

```
public void flip(Node head, Node tail){ 
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.data = head.data;
    temp.next = null; // (2)
    tail.next = temp; // (3)
    head = head.next; // (1)
}
```

Comment: I updated my code in the question. I would really appreciate if you looked at it. So that would change for example a linked list of A->B->C->D to B->C->D->A?

Comment: Okay so if what I have in the question works, what is the difference with that and what you edited in to your answer?

Comment: @D.Hoffman Well the sequence is something to take care of, just for example, if you point `tail.next` after updating the head to its next, then you might end up having something like B->C->D->B

Comment: Okay and I'm learning about running time too... the running time of my method id O(1) correct

Comment: @D.Hoffman You mean *time complexity* probably? Should be, yes.